# Connecting to multiple devices

Tags: c#, telnet, tcpclient

I have 14 different devices which I need to establish a connection at the same time and every few minutes to re-check the connection status.

I'm wondering if I need to make a thread for each one of them or if there is a better way to do it.

```
public partial class Automation : Form
{
        public Automation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //======================================================================
        TelnetConnection Telnet1 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.21", 9090);
        TelnetConnection Telnet2 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.22", 9090);
        TelnetConnection Telnet3 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.23", 9090);
        TelnetConnection Telnet4 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.24", 9090);
        TelnetConnection Telnet5 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.25", 9090);
        TelnetConnection Telnet6 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.26", 9090);
        TelnetConnection Telnet7 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.27", 9090);
        //======================================================================
        TelnetConnection ADV1 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.1", 9090);
        TelnetConnection ADV2 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.2", 9090);
        TelnetConnection ADV3 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.3", 9090);
        TelnetConnection ADV4 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.4", 9090);
        TelnetConnection ADV5 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.5", 9090);
        TelnetConnection ADV6 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.6", 9090);
        TelnetConnection ADV7 = new TelnetConnection("10.10.100.7", 9090);
        //======================================================================
        private void Automation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //===========Check Online State===========//
            Check_Online_Offline_State();
            //===========Check Online State===========//
        }
}
```

Also I'll be sending each one of the devices commands whenever needed 
but the problem is with telnet connections because they run into exception after 3 connections but if I run only the advs it establishes a connection fine.

Suggestions?

Comment: _"they run into exception"_ — WHAT EXCEPTION?

Comment: if one of the IPs is not online or cant be reached the program wont load at all

Answer (score 1):

Use Parallel.ForEach, it is asynchronous multi-threading and less code, just sample:

```
  private TelnetConnection[] m_Connections;
  ...
  m_Connections = new TelnetConnection[50];
  for (var i = 0; i < m_Connections.Length; i++)
  {
    m_Connections[i] = new TelnetConnection(string.Concat("10.10.100.", i), 9090);
  }
  ...
  Parallel.ForEach(m_Connections, conn =>
  {
    bool isAlive = conn.IsHostAlive();
  });
```

Comment: i need also to be able to send to each of them command at different times

Comment: You can extend it by yourself. That was only sample, to use multithreading and less typing.